# Access .env variables in .mdx file | Remix

Tags: reactjs, remix

What is the best way to access environment variables in a `.mdx` file.
Remix's approach to accessing `.env` variables in a normal component is to use the loader data hook (`useLoaderData()`). However, hooks cannot be used so easily in `.mdx` files.
I also tried passing the environment variables via props from the parent component, but that didn't work either, as I couldn't figure out which library Remix uses to work with `.mdx` files.
cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't figure out how to pass the props to the Component, but I found a somewhat good workaround. I created a `ContactText` component whose only task is to read the `contactConfig` and return the desired config property value.

`ContactText.tsx`

```
const ContactText: React.FC<TProps> = (props) => {
  const { contactConfig } = useRootContext();
  const { contactConfigPath, as, ...rest } = props;

  const getValue = React.useCallback((): string => {
    const contactConfigPathParts = contactConfigPath.split('.');
    let currentValue = contactConfig;
    for (const part of contactConfigPathParts) {
      if (currentValue != null) {
        currentValue = (currentValue as any)[part];
      }
    }
    return typeof currentValue === 'string' ? currentValue : 'unknown';
  }, [contactConfig, contactConfigPath]);

  return as != null ? (
    React.createElement(as, {
      children: getValue(),
      ...rest,
    })
  ) : (
    <>{getValue()}</>
  );
};

export default ContactText;

type TProps = {
  contactConfigPath: string;
  as?: React.ElementType;
};
```

`whatever.mdx`

```
// ..


Phone: <ContactText contactConfigPath={'phoneNumber'} />

<ContactText contactConfigPath={'address.postCode'} />

// ..
```